# Differenza tra: socio-economico e economico-sociale?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

L'ho visto scritto in entrambi i modi, e non sono riuscito a capire dal contesto le differenze tra i due termini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se la [definizione di socioeconomico](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/socioeconomico/) è:

> socioeconòmico agg. [comp. di socio- e economico] (pl. m. -ci). – Detto di fenomeno o aspetto di una data società considerato nell’insieme dei rapporti o delle interrelazioni sociali ed economiche.

intuitivamente la definizione di "economico-sociale" potrebbe essere

> economico-sociale agg. [comp. di economico e sociale]. – Detto di fenomeno o aspetto economico considerato nell’insieme dei rapporti o delle interrelazioni economiche e sociali.

Le differenze possono essere molte e importanti: nel primo caso l'oggetto principale della tua attenzione è la società, entro cui si svolgono le relazioni economiche; nel secondo è l'economia che determina i rapporti sociali. Ciò può avere implicazioni teoriche, ideologiche: per esempio nella filosofia marxiana si parla di "[formazioni economico-sociali](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/formazioni-economico-sociali_%28Enciclopedia_delle_scienze_sociali%29/)"; anche nel campo della giurisprudenza, in diritto privato, la [funzione "economico-sociale"](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/diritto/approfondimenti/diritto_civile/1_Galati.html) può accompagnare quella "economico-giuridica"; in economia politica può essere d'interesse lo studio delle conseguenze sociali di scelte di politica economica, gli effetti economico-sociali; etc.